# Javascript error ( missing } )

Tags: javascript, jquery

Just checking my JS and I have an error, but I cannot see where. WOnder if you can ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('input').hover(function()
        {
        $(this).popover('show')
        });
        $("#loginnow").validate({
            rules:{
                username:{
                    required:true,
                    minlength: 3
                },
                password:{
                    required:true,
                    minlength: 6
                },
            messages:{
                username:{
                    required:"Enter your Username",
                    minlength:"Username must be minimum 3 characters"
                },
                password:{
                    required:"Enter your password",
                    minlength:"Password must be minimum 6 characters"
                },
                    },
            errorClass: "help-inline",
            errorElement: "span",
            highlight:function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
                $(element).parents('.control-group').addClass('error');
            },
            unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
                $(element).parents('.control-group').removeClass('error');
                $(element).parents('.control-group').addClass('success');
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: @MohitBumb why is this a stupid question? The writer has an error in their code and can't find it. Your comment is offensive.

Comment: @422 learn to use jshint/jslint for such petty validations.

Comment: @Preet Sngha I tried via jslint prior to posting here. Still throwing errors in firebug, I was going googly eyed lol.

Comment: @MohitBumb you could state your opinions in more polite way. Rudeness is not welcome on stackoverflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [jshint](http://www.jshint.com/).

Here is your report: http://www.jshint.com/reports/623021

Comment: Thankyou I was using jslint, and it mentions line numbers but doesnt display line numbers. Much better code inspector tool thankyou

Comment: @422 mention not :) dont forget to accept the answer & thus close the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
rules:{
```

you didn't close this braces please check in dreamweaver